# How to create a component in a custom hook that handles state within the hook?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

How can I create a component in a custom hook where the hook holds the state for the component?

My attempt basically does the right thing, but drag-and-drop is not working as expected. Instead the slider will **only change the value on click**. I think the problem is, that the useState hook gets called outside of the `X` definition. But how can we create a component in a hook then where I need to work with the state of that internal component within the rest of the hook?

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-milu3?file=/demo.js:0-391

```
import React from "react";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";

function useComp() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(30);
  const X = () => <Slider value={value} onChange={(_, v) => setValue(v)} />;
  return { X, value };
}

export default function ContinuousSlider() {
  const { X, value } = useComp();
  return (
    <div>
      {value}
      <X />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: Slider with custom hook not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57433546/react-slider-with-custom-hook-not-working-properly)

Comment: @GalAbra While the underlying problem is the same (loosing event handlers on re-renders), the provided solution to the other question is not helpful in my case because I depend on the hook to do much more logic while the solution suggests not using hooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever the custom hook is called (on each render), a new Slider (`Broken`) component is created. Since a new component is created, the event handlers are recreated as well, and the drag is cancelled. You can solve this problem in two ways:

Wrap the component in `useCallback()`, and pass the `value` when rendering the component ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-4tmq2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)):

```
  const Broken = useCallback(({ value }) => (
    <Slider value={value} onChange={changeHandler} />
  ), [changeHandler]);

  // usage
  <Broken value={broken} />
```

Render the component in the hook, and use the include it in the component ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-x9kts?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)):

```
function useComp() {
  const [broken, setBroken] = React.useState(30);

  const changeHandler = useCallback((_, v) => setBroken(v), []);

  const slider = <Slider value={broken} onChange={changeHandler} />;

  return { slider, broken };
}

// usage

<div>
  Broken: {broken}
  {slider}
  OK: {ok}
  <Slider value={ok} onChange={(_, v) => setOk(v)} />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve my actual problem based on your answer. I also require the hook to create different components based on a parameter of the custom hook `useComp(type)`, For this I also needed a `useMemo` on the logic that decides which component to create `Fixed = useMemo(() => { switch(type) {... <Slider chaneValue={setValueCallback} ... });`

Comment: oh and special thanks for providing 2 solutions. Also the other related question provides a third solution by not using hooks at all.

Comment: You're welcome. Actually the answer in the related question is the one I would normally use. However, there are special cases where you actually need a custom component created in a hook, or another function.